# Organizing firebase data

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth and Firebase Database to store student's profiles and students reports.

When the user signs up they input email, password, school name, school year, school discipline. I use the email and password for the Auth but the rest of the info is stored in the Database with a unique ID as shown below:

[image]

For the reports, each students can input many entries, each with its unique ID as shown below:

[image]

Here are my questions:

1. Once a student logs in, how can I find their profile info since the parent is a unique ID. In other words is there a way to search through the database for that students email (for example, mido4@hotmail.com, in the image) and from that get the students name (in this case, Emina Osman)?
2. Once you get the student's name, how can you search for all the entries that student has saved in the database? For each entry the student has, the student name is saved.
3. Not sure if the way I setup the database is ideal so is there a better way?

Thanks for your time! Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is. The simplest way to achieve this, is to change your database structure a little bit. So instead of using as a unique identifier, the pushed key, generated by the `push()` method, i suggets you using the **email address**. It's also unique and easy to use. The benefit is, that is allows you to search your database for that particular email. Your database structure should look like this:

   ```
   flashscreen-1d252
        |
        --- Users
              |
              --- mido4@hotmail,com
              |      |
              |      --- //User Details
              |  
              --- mido5@hotmail,com
                     |
                     --- //User Details
   ```

Note, that Firebase does not allow symbols as `.` (dot) to be used in a key. So as you probably see, i have changed the `.` dot with a `,` (comma). I have achieved this using the below method:

```
String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}
```

To search for an user and get the name, simply add a listener on `Users` node like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("mido4@hotmail,com");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            String firstName = dataSnapshot.child("firstname").getValue(String.class);
            String lastName = dataSnapshot.child("lastname").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", firstName + " " + lastName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be: `Emina Osman`

2. You'll have to search after the email address and not after the name.
3. Already answered above. This database structure is more efficient.

**Edit:** There 2 additional questions regarding this answer based on using the email address vs. uid.

1. What if a user decides to delete his account and after a while decides to return and tries to sign-in again? If we are using the `email address`, nothing happens. If we are using the `uid`, when the user signs in for the second time, another `uid` is generated, which is obvious that is different from the first one and this the moment in which you are in trouble, because even he is the same user, he is treated as a new one.
2. What if the users email address changes? IMHO, an email can be changed only if you decide to change it. Personally, I haven't changed my email address in years but I have deleted hundreds of accounts from hundreds of applications. Even if you change your email address, there's no much of a problem. You login in your application, change the email address and that's it. You'll have also all your history within that application. Having a unique identifier a `uid`, in case you delete the account and you come back again, you start from zero.

Comment: @mido2009 Do not do this!!! Using email addresses as keys is a huge problem! What if the users email address changes? You would have to remove the node, re-write it and also change *every other reference to that node*! You also have to deal with removing special characters and bunch of other stuff. Also, you are leaning heavily on queries which are slower than directly accessing a node and also are require a lot more resources. It's always better to directly access nodes instead of query'ing for them if possible.

Comment: Oh see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386373/compare-textfield-text-to-firebase-string-swift/41387240#41387240) for a bit of additional information.

Comment: Mido2009, @Jay is one of the best answerers around here, but please see my updated answer. It's up to you to to decide which option is best for you but according to Firebase team, i thik this is the right one. Jay, tell me if my wrong. What i wanted to explain, that my answer is a common practice when it comes to Firebase that i have seen in many projects.

Comment: Your answer is good for sure. The OP needs to decide what's best for their use case. I was trying to save some grief as having the ability to change an email may be needed. See the following posts from Firebaser's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774694/adding-a-dynamic-child-to-my-firebase-reference-url/15775182#15775182) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350486/how-to-authenticate-escaped-email-based-user-accounts-in-firebase/19352215#19352215). The other nice thing about Firebase generated keys is they are sequential and stacked whereas emails are not.

Comment: On #2, I would disagree. If an email address is updated, it can be a huge problem. Remember that we're not talking about a single node here, we're talking about dozens of nodes across the app because Firebase data is typically denormalized so there will be many references/duplicates of that email address. When changed, every node in the entire database will need to be read in, deleted and written back out with the new email: a *lot* of additional code. Using uid as the parent node and the email as a child node, all of the references point back to the uid, so changing the email has no impact.

Comment: @Jay Both answers are talking about the benefit of using the uid but none of them talks about what happens if the users deletes his account. So, even if we are not talking about a single node, in the same way we add data, we can update/delete. I don't think that it will be much complicated. We can use atomic multi-location writes, which either all updates succeed or all updates fail. So, it's up to OP to decide. By the way, thanks Jay! It's always a pleasure ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Once a student logs in, how can I find their profile info since the
>   parent is a unique ID.

Super easy! When a users account is created initially, Firebase assigns the user a 'random' and unchanging user uid (uid). That uid is what identified that specific user to Firebase. That's what you should store there info under within the users node like this:

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "users name"
```

Then when they authenticate in the future, firebase provides that uid to you in the authentication process. You can then simply get their user information from the users node via that uid.  i.e. read the node  /users/uid_0

> Once you get the student's name, how can you search for all the
>   entries that student has saved in the database?

Again, super simple. For every entry you make in Firebase, reference that uid. For example, say you want to keep track of each users reports

```
reports
   uid_0
     -9i9sdjj3i0a09djads  //create with push() or childByAutoId() in swift
        reportName: "some report"
     -ua9sd9i9i3i0idsfi
        reportName: "another report"
```

Then to get all of their reports, read the node /reports/uid_0

conversely, you can store the reports and then a link to the user

```
reports
  -9i9sdjj3i0a09djads
     reportName: "some report"
     report_by: "uid_0"
```

and with that structure a query can be done where report_by is equal to "uid_0" to return all of uid_0's reports.

> Not sure if the way I setup the database is ideal so is there a better
>   way?

there's a number of different ways to achieve what you want but the above is a very common design pattern.

Comment: Jay and Alex, Thanks a lot to both of you!! this is very helpful.

Comment: I have two more questions that I need help with: there are a limited number of reports that can be submitted, lets say 10 different possible reports. 
(1) How can I check if the report exists or not? I would have to check the values of "location",  "mode",  "spinnerOne"  and compare them to what the user just entered and if its already there then don't add to the database and if it is then add it. I used a for loop to go through the reports but its not working for me. (2) I have the reports in a listview and I want to allow the users to delete reports how should I go about it?

Comment: @Mido2009 That's really another question but you would couple a compound value (specs: location_mode_spinnerOne) with an observeSingleEvent to see if that node already exists. Do some research on that and post another question with some details and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Mido2009 Decided you didn't like my answer? Was there some other question about it that was not answered?